# How to ensure smooth autoplay of video in flutter App splash screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, video

I'm currently developing an app in Flutter which uses a Splash screen that plays an mp4 video upon startup. The video I've obtained has been exported from Adobe After effects in 24fps, yet I think that practically all smartphones of nowadays, even the cheap ones, support 60fps. I thus increased the fps-rate of the mp4-video file to 60fps, but it is still not running smoothly (in testing mode, no matter the iOS or Android simulator, or even a test on physical devices), but rather staggery / the animations are not fluent, although they perfectly are if the video is played on a laptop, for example.

The video is simply loaded into the projects by loading it into the `assets` folder of the flutter project, then:

- Adding this in pubspec.yml:

```
  assets:
    - assets/videos/final_60fps.mp4
```

and then playing the video using:

```
/// Called in initState()
Future<void> _initVideoPlayer() async {

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/final_60fps.mp4');
    _controller.setVolume(0.0);
    _controller.addListener(() => setState(() {
      /// Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
    }));
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture =
        _controller.initialize().then((_) => _controller.play());

  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't think the code is the problem. **(1)** What resolution at 60 FPS are using? A smaller resolution might help. **(2)** Is using 30 FPS an option for you (since it would be less frames to process per second)? **(3)** If using MP4 then try saving the video codec (H264) under the "Baseline Profile" since that plays smoothly even on old devices.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! In the end I gave up on the mp4 and the use of video player, and learned about lottie videos, which is now running like a charm using the devices refresh rate via TickerProviderStateMixin! I suppose the big problem was your point (1), all images of the animation are around 15Kb, but one was around 1500 pixels wide. That was most likely too much to process for a mobile screen, but not for a high power and max resolution laptop. The lottie (vectorized) version of the video did the trick, while also reducing the videos size from 1MB to 40KB!

Comment: You should post that as an actual Answer below. Sounds useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up on the mp4 and the use of video player, and learned about lottie videos, which is now running like a charm using the devices refresh rate [via TickerProviderStateMixin](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie#specify-a-custom-animationcontroller)! I suppose the big problem was that one image used in the animation was around 1500 pixels wide. That was most likely too much to process for a mobile screen, but not for a high power and max resolution laptop. The lottie (vectorized) version of the video did the trick, while also reducing the videos size from 1MB to 40KB!

Regarding platform support when you implement your lottie video, make sure you check the [list of supported features](https://lottiefiles.com/supported-features).